# Significance of Whiplash's presence in the very last scene of "The Unit"

Tags: plot-explanation, the-unit

At the very last scene of the TV show ["The Unit"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0460690/), when all of the crew is in the chapel for Grey's wedding (except Col. Ryan,) you can see "Whiplash" in the back looking remorsefully at "Redcap".  My question is whether Whiplash's presence signifies the unit's forgiveness of his actions or merely tolerance/understanding, leaving him as an outsider forever looking in?